# Is there any module to generate barcode from number in Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

For barcode scanning there are modules available like [Redlaser](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5222?2035817094),[Scandit](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/3907?1098951835)..etc.
Is there any module to generate barcode from number(reverse procedure)?

Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/134506/bar-code-generator-for-iphone, http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/84221/barcode-generator have you checked these links?

Comment: Hi Anand, I tried by your given links, but in both cases inner links are broken(SpiralArm). And it seems that no one gave any kind of module description which performs this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Scandit api's available for this implementation [Here is the working example link](http://www.scandit.com/barcode-generator/),

[Here is instructions how to use it.](http://www.scandit.com/2012/12/11/create-your-own-barcodes-with-scandits-new-barcode-generator/)

Hope this may help some one else also.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A nice trick to avoid the main of modules, you can simply download a Barcode font, embed it in your app, and simply show a label with the text and the barcode font.

Be sure to check if the font is real, some are just artists conceptions and do not generate actual barcodes. Just make a few tests with a scanner app before you launch!

M_